# How to install an application from Github?

Tags: software-installation, github

a beginner needs your help!

I am looking to install this app on Ubuntu 22.04:

https://github.com/brandizzi/input-device-indicator

However, I have no clue on how to do it - could you help me with step-by-step instructions?

Should I download the whole project first, then execute it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Before instructions can be offered, it’ll be important to know which version of Ubuntu you’re using, as this application doesn’t look to be compatible with each flavour. Could you [edit] your question to include the exact version you’re using?

Comment: It's not just installing. You also need to know how to uninstall it properly. This does not seem a good task for a beginner. Too many things can go wrong when you follow magic shell incantations that you do not understand.

Comment: What's the reason for building it yourself instead of installing the pre-built package?

Comment: @matigo thank you, edited!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `Makefile` seems pretty easy:

1. First you need to make sure you have `python` and `make` installed. You can check by running `python3 --version` and `make --version`. If you get an error on either of the commands you need to install it.
2. Clone the repo if you haven't done it already.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/brandizzi/input-device-indicator.git
cd input-device-indicator
```

3. Create a virtual environment to build the app (unless you want to install the dependencies on your system).

```bash
python3 -m venv app-build
```

PS: You might need to install `python3.10-venv` package.

```bash
apt install python3.10-venv
```

4. Activate the virtual environment.

```bash
source app-build/bin/activate
```

5. Install the dependencies.

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
```

Note that you might need to remove the 1st line from the `requirements.txt` file or just run the following command if you get an error while trying to install it:

```bash
cat requirements.txt | tail -n +2 | xargs -n1 pip install
```

6. Install the app on your system.

```bash
make install_local
```

Note that on my Ubuntu VM i had to install a few extra packages that were required. I'll leave a command to install them too if you get any errors.

```bash
apt install python3-all debhelper dh-python
```